# How to connect to mongo database in docker from another machine using ruby code

Tags: ruby, mongodb, docker

In my ruby code, I'm trying to use `Mongo::Client.new("mongodb://#{uname}:#{passwd}@#{host}:#{port}/#{db}")` to connect to a mongo database on another machine's docker in Kubernetes cluster.

But the result says that

> getaddrinfo: Name or service not known. `#<Mongo::Client:0x16434420 cluster=#<Cluster
>   topology=ReplicaSetNoPrimary[ip:port,mongo-0.mongo-hs.db.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongo-1.mongo-hs.db.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongo-2.mongo-hs.db.svc.cluster.local:27017,name=MainRepSet]
>   servers=[#<Server address=mongo-0.mongo-hs.db.svc.cluster.local:27017
>   UNKNOWN>,#<Server address=mongo-1.mongo-hs.db.svc.cluster.local:27017
>   UNKNOWN>,#<Server address=mongo-2.mongo-hs.db.svc.cluster.local:27017
>   UNKNOWN>]>>`

However, when I use `pymongo` in a python script. I can connect to the database.

Is there a way for ruby code to connect to the database directly?

Answer (score 0):

1. In an irb console, execute the call to create the client that you have posted. The default logging level of the driver is info which will give you a lot of information about what is going on. Use that information to further debug and include it in your question.
2. If pymongo can connect and ruby driver cannot, one possibility is your dns is misconfigured in one or both of the containers. Ruby driver requires your system to be able to resolve the hostnames given to the driver.